# Iphone does not recognize favicons

Tags: android, html, ios, favicon

having some problems with favicons on an Iphone.

I added the following code in the header right after the title and before my css files:

```
<!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display running iOS ≥ 7: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">

<!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display running iOS ≤ 6: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">

<!-- For non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">

<link rel="icon" href="/icon_32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

All my favicon files are located in the root folder and there is also favicon.ico to support older browsers.

Somehow, my iphone do not show any favicon, when I add the page to favorites and when i try to add to home screen, it just uses the snapshot of the page as an icon. On my android device the icons work well.

Where might be the problem? And maybe any advice on how can i debug this issue on my iphone directly?

Best Regards,
Gleb.

Answer (score 0):

**First things first**: try reloading the website 3 or four times. It may be a server issue.

If it doesn't work, try to get a good looking(i.e. big size) icon of your website and make yourself a new package at
[Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) It is the real deal for favicons for any browser and any size. Customizable and easy to use. It gives you the code to use et caetera.

It worked for me.